# Undefined index during post request in php when passing a javascript object

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I am using a php file as a API but i am getting an `undefined index` when making a post command in php. I can't access the `Object` parameter that I passed. What am I doing wrong?

Javascript code:

```
var user = {
            'name': 'Wayne',
            'country': 'Ireland'
        };
var userStr = JSON.stringify(user);
axios.post('http://localhost/test2/test.php',{user: userStr})
.then(r=>{console.log(r)})
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type,multipart/form-data, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
echo $_POST['user'];
?>
```

Comment: this might help... [unable to post data in axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1195)

Comment: Are you really just calling `$_POST['user']` or the inner values? Can you show us the full error message?

Comment: @jibsteroos post your answer that discussion solved my problem. Not the way that I want it but it still works.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I am at school so I can't give you the exact message but it something between the line `user is undefined`

Comment: If you could post the (unsatisfactory, but apparently effective) solution that worked for you, please do so - there are many (half-way) solutions in that thread, I can't determine which one worked for you. Happy it helped you solve your issue though :-)